# Altium jump from component in PCB editor to schematic

Tags: altium

Is there a way to highlight a component in the Altium PCB designer and then jump to its location in the schematic editor? I have a hierarchical schematic so it can be a pain to have to search through each schematic sheet to find where the component is located when using cross probing. I found that I can just search the designator and the schematic link will pop up but I was wondering if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: Tools -> Cross Probe. Alternatively, in the schematic, open the item manager. This lists every component and which sheet it is on.

Comment: This link will take you, even without a valid license, to an excellent (and official) Altium forum: https://forum.live.altium.com (where all you need to do is register for an account).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To enable this feature, you must initially activate the cross-probe function as depicted below. Once activated, navigate to either the schematic or PCB environment. After that right-click your mouse, then select cross-probe after that holding down the control key and clicking on the desired component. Proceed to your schematic or PCB section.

[image: Cross Select Mode]

However, for optimal efficiency, it's preferable to initially divide your Altium screen into two vertical or horizontal sections.

[image: Split Option]

and then click on the part you want in the schematic environment, then use this option [Reposition Selected component] in the PCB environment as the picture.

[image: Reposition option]