# How to find an already placed schematic symbol in Altium schematic

Tags: altium

I have a large multi-sheet schematic in Altium, which uses the multi-part schematic symbol for an LS1046 CPU. This part has 15+ components, which across the multiple sheets of the schematic are hard to keep track of? How do I find a specific part of the  mutli-part symbol?

Normally I would use the search bar in the top right, but this only contains the First of the parts (in this case U2A), and clicking on the search result brings me to a random part of the symbol (in my case, U2G).

Additionally, having clicked on the search result, I get green lines connecting to all the other symbol parts on the same schematic sheet - how do I get rid of these??

Comment: Hi @Mauvai I think this answer link will help you https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/704016/366167

Comment: @Alirezaagha30 While this il helpful that seems to be jumping me to the pcb layout, while iI want to see results from other schematic pages

Comment: Use the Item Manager (under tools in a schematic view). Each part of the symbol is listed for multi-part symbols.

Comment: @PeterSmith this is a workable solution, thanks! If you want to make your comment a full answer I can accept it

Comment: Comment converted to an answer with pretty pic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multi-part symbols are listed individually in the 'ItemManager'.

In a schematic context (you need at least one schematic sheet open but which one doesn't matter) Use **Tools** -> **Item Manager...**.

You will get a view of this type:

[image: Item Manager view]

As you can see, one of the parts I am using has three parts to the symbol and each is listed. Just to the right is the schematic sheet in which each resides.

The item manager view will show all the sub-parts for any such device together.

Answer (score 2):

In your schematic, **E**dit > **J**ump > Jump **C**omponent (Alt+E..J..C)

Type in the designator into the pop up box
[image]

If it is a multi-part component, a second box will open, where you can cycle between parts, and the schematic will jump to that part.

[image]